# RSS Invalid Feed

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, rss

http://validator.w3.org/appc/check.cgi?url=craft.tutsplus.com%2F%3Ffeed%3Dapp

Anyone got any idea what the error is? It certainly isn't what it is pointing to...

Answer (score 0):

On lines 246 and 247 you have invalid characters (Unicode 0x7) just inside the `<li>` elements.

[image]